# How do I update a string value in a hash-map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Why doesn't this work?

```
(def app-state (atom {:title "foo"}))

(swap! app-state update-in [:title] "bar")
```

All the examples I could find for update-in work on numerical values as opposed to a string.

It throws a class cast exception in Clojure, and

```
Unhandled clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo
 #object[TypeError TypeError: f.call is not a function]
```

in ClojureScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `assoc` or `assoc-in`:

```
(def app-state (atom {:title "foo"}))

(swap! app-state assoc     :title "bazz")   => {:title "bazz"}
(swap! app-state assoc-in [:title] "bar")   => {:title "bar"}
```

`update` and `update-in` require a function, rather than a value like
`assoc` and `assoc-in`.  In your example the string `"bar"` would be used as a
function, but strings can not be called, hence you see the error.

So, you can also use a function that ignores its argument and always returns the same thing.

```
(swap! app-state update-in [:title] (fn [_] "fizz"))      => {:title "fizz"}
(swap! app-state update-in [:title] (constantly "buzz"))  => {:title "buzz"}
```

Of course, this kind of defeats the reason to use an `update` instead of `assoc` in the first place.